# Creating a simple subroutine in fortran

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I am new to Fortran and I had made a program where everything did fit into one single file, which worked. 
However when i tried to take out parts and put them into modules and subroutines I quickly ran into problems. 
*Even after removing everything and having only the bare minimum left, it still gives an error regarding the subroutine.*

Currently the heavily reduced main program looks like this. It only uses the module and calls the subroutine.

```
program test
    use mod1
    call sub1(var)
end program test
```

and the module looks like:

```
Module mod1
    implicit none
    type A
        real                     :: type1
    end type A

contains
    subroutine sub1(var)
        type(A)  :: var
        var%type1 = 1+1
    end subroutine sub1
```

However I seem to do something wrong here and unfortunately I can not figure out what. I get the error

```
 ||Error: Type mismatch in argument 'var'  ; passed REAL(4) to TYPE(a)|
end module mod1
```

Can someone please explain which fundamental mistake I am making in order to prevent the most basic subroutine from working?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Fortran, but you never create `var` in the main program... could this be the problem?

Comment: Best I can figure without a compiler handy and decades since very minimal Fortran experience, the problem is that `var` is (implicitly) defined to be a `REAL`, whereas `A` only _contains_ a `REAL`.  I think you need something like...`type (A) var` before you call `sub1()`.  Fortran is _very_ picky about data types.  If you copy the definition of `A` into the main program, that will fail with an even more cryptic error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your program you do not explicitly declare `var`.  In days of yore Fortran supported *implicit typing* and, by default, variables whose name begin with a `v` will be of type `real`.  Fortran retains this capability, though its use is now frowned upon.

I think you are thinking (as if I had a clue what you are thinking) that `var` in the program scope will somehow be automatically associated with, or the same as,  `var` in the subroutine in the module.  It won't be.

Do these things:

- Insert `implicit none` on the line after `use mod1` in your program.
- Explicitly declare `var` within the program, *eg* `type(a) :: var`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This solved my initial problem.
However, it did cause a new problem. If i use the write command in the main program it only prints the number 2 as expected. But when i add a second type in the module, for example the type integer. Then the write command will print over 40 numbers, while the newly created type is never used and somehow still messes up the write command: write(*,*) var

Comment: If you've got a new question, ask a new question.  Trying to figure out what you have crammed into a comment is just too difficult.